# moving items from a folder to another but within another subdirectory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, move

I have the text files in one file (C:/test/ex135). I want to move these files onto a new destination but the ex135 is hidden inside another directory named bob. So I would want to move these text files to C:/test/bob/ex135. Can I have powershell search for "ex135" within certain file path and move items here? If I knew the destination file, I would simply do `copy-item -path "C:/test/ex135" -Destination "C/test/bob/ex135"` but the destination path is not clear (I would want powershell to find this destination).

Comment: moving/copying all/one file/files from C:/test/ex135 to C:/test/bob/ex135? is ex135 file or directory?

Comment: ex135 is a directory. I want to move C:/test/ex135/allfiles -> C:/test/bob/ex135/allfiles (so moving transferring "allfiles" over).

Comment: `move-item -path "C:\test\ex135\*.txt" -Destination "C:\test\bob\ex135"`

Comment: but I wouldn't know the destination. I would want powershell to find "ext135" pattern in that other directory by itself

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all txt files to be transported are in `c:\test\ex135`

the target folder is ex135 but in an unknown subdirectory, somewhere deep down c:\test\bob

then

```
$find_ex135 = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\bob" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.StartsWith("ex135")}
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\*.txt | Move-Item -Destination $find_ex135.FullName
```

Comment: `StartsWith()` is Case-Sensitive, that may cause a problem. Also, the `Get-ChildItem` may find multiple folders with a name like that, or maybe even none at all..

Comment: @Theo you are right, but it works for the narrow case Bee described. Could you post the answer? that would be helpful. thanks